# Error Creating Site Collection without UPA

Tags: 2013, user-profile, site-collection

I am trying to create a new site collection in my sandbox environment via central administration and receive the below error:

> UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID has null proxy

I am having the same issue as this open post via Office Dev center and have tried all suggestions in the post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49d55dc2-60f9-4434-b140-d9b2d68372d8/sharepoint-2013-cannot-create-site-collection?forum=sharepointadmin

I have also tried creating the site collection via PowerShell. Ran Config Wizard post patch, IIS reset, server reboot, starting the User Profile service etc.

Like the above post, we have implemented the 10/17 patch and do not need UPA in this environment as it is solely a test box.

Comment: This does appear to be patch related.... https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/10/october-2017-cu-site-creation-error-sharepoint-foundation-2013/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this yesterday. Oct patch appears to be the common link. 
The problem happened after creating the Web App for the My Site Host, could not create a Site Collection in order to create the UPSA. Chicken and Egg.

Finally created the Site Collection in PowerShell after deleting the first content database on the web app that contained an orphaned root site collection. Once the new Site Collection was created for the My Site Host web app I could create the User Profile Service Application. Then the CreateSite page started working.

Does seem like a bug in the Oct CU.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in October 10, 2017 update [KB4011173](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011173/october-10-2017-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013) and its fix has been provided in next month November 14, 2017 update [KB4011256](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4011256/november-14-2017-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb4011256).

Hope that helps someone.